# docker registry and nginx - Entity too large - client_max_body_size has no effect

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-registry

I have deployed `docker registry` for Image storage with `S3` as storage.

Some of my images are in `GBs`, so I have set the nginx property `client_max_body_size` to `5GB`, but it's still giving me this error.

`error parsing HTTP 413 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html>\r\n<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center>`

## 413 Request Entity Too Large

**registry**

```
upstream registry_upstream{
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server {
  server_name  registry.domain.com;
  # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
  client_max_body_size 0;
  location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://registry_upstream;

   }

 # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = registry.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name  registry.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have moved `client_max_body_size` attribute to `http` directive in `nginx.conf`.

```
http {
    client_max_body_size 0;

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        .....
   }
}
```